# Can;t get MySql/Mariadb to use spatial index

Tags: mysql, spatial-index

This is using 5.5.68-MariaDB. Yes, I know this is very old but I have to use this version for this application for the time being.

The explain and the performance of the query clearly show the indexes aren't being used. Here's the info:

```
explain select bdcfabric.location_id from bdccoverage, bdcfabric where
 st_intersects(bdccoverage.shape,bdcfabric.bxlocation)\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: bdccoverage
         type: ALL
possible_keys: SHAPE
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 886
        Extra:
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: bdcfabric
         type: ALL
possible_keys: bxlocation_idx
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1105588
        Extra: Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)
```

The indexes:

```
show indexes from bdccoverage\G
*************************** 4. row ***************************
        Table: bdccoverage
   Non_unique: 1
     Key_name: SHAPE
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: SHAPE
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: NULL
     Sub_part: 32
       Packed: NULL
         Null:
   Index_type: SPATIAL
      Comment:
Index_comment:

show indexes from bdcfabric\G
*************************** 2. row ***************************
        Table: bdcfabric
   Non_unique: 1
     Key_name: bxlocation_idx
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: bxlocation
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: NULL
     Sub_part: 32
       Packed: NULL
         Null:
   Index_type: SPATIAL
      Comment:
Index_comment:
```

The schema:

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| SHAPE      | geometry    | NO   | MUL |         |                |

describe bdcfabric;
+-------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                   | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| bxlocation              | point      | NO   | MUL |         |       |
+-------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Why aren't the indexes being used?

Comment: Is this relevant?  "The optimizer ignores SPATIAL indexes on columns that have no SRID attribute (and thus are not SRID-restricted). MySQL still maintains such indexes, as follows:"

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.

Comment: Since one thing is a `POINT`, see if `ST_Within()` or `ST_Contains()` works better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query needs to run all locations of `bdcfabric.bxlocation` against `bdccoverage.shape` in the other table. These kinds of joins where the join criteria is complex (like `st_intersects`) don't lead themselves to index usage.

Even on this old version, increasing [join_buffer_size](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/block-based-join-algorithms/#size-of-join-buffers) / [join_buffer_space_limit](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#join_buffer_space_limit). Look at the session [rows_read](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-status-variables/#rows_read) on the default size for the query compared to when you increase it.

Comment: Sorry do you mean run a query for every single location against the shape? The bdcfabric table is 1 million rows! Is this a restriction for all mariadb versions? Is prostgres better in this regard?

Comment: You are running the query for every location against every shape. Another thing to try is using `ST_GeomCollFromText(CONCAT('GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(', GROUP_CONCAT(ST_AsText(bdccoverage.shape)), ')'))` as a subquery on the 886 shapes and then apply that to `bdcfabric`. It may not use an index, but it will be a single pass of both tables than some form of cross-product.

Comment: OK, just being sure, yes, we tried the query for every single location. At over a million of those, that seemed to take day(s) to complete. So we abandoned this altogether in favor of offloading the work to a postgres/postgis instance. The intersect there for these tables took about 12 seconds.